# Broken CMD, cmder, and powershell. Cmder is automatically executing commands on launch

Tags: command-line, powershell, cmder

I recently made a node.js project for the first time, and honestly I had to put my Windows 7 PC through hell trying to get it to run (more info below). However since then, my system has not been the same with it's cmd applications.

1. a fresh copy of cmder on start up will display: `'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` but otherwise works fine.
2. attempting to run cmder from laragon will fail with message

```
'js' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Current directory:
D:\Applications\laragon\www

Command to be executed:
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C js rest API with express and mongodb SOLID\code\node-api" cmd /k "D:\Applications\laragon\bin\cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\..\init.bat"


ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

**Notably** the program I created is in path of `D:\{...folders...}code\node js rest API with express and mongodb SOLID\code\node-api`. One of the biggest issues I had before with node.js terminal, cmd terminal, and both cmder terminals is that it would NOT let me cd into this folder (nor any folder not on C drive). I think I poked around a bit according to other online forums/questions but eventually gave up and would just repeat the command and restarting cmd until it worked. However, if I broke something here I still don't see why cmder should be attempting to access this folder on launch anyway. (Because I know `node` is a start of a node command, but why does it have this path being injected at launch anyway, and also why would it not read it as a path but as a `node` command?). Even not having that path exist on my PC doesn't change anything, but that must mean somewhere on my PC the string `code\node js rest API with express and mongodb SOLID\code\node-api` exists somewhere and is the cause of at least this part of the problem.

3. attempting to right click in explorer > Terminal (context menu from Laragon/cmder) crashes instantly with message `cmder is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` that can only be seen with a quick printscreen.
4. attempting to use terminal window in Visual Studio 2019 creates an unclosable dialogue box with title `powershell.exe` that says `Windows cannot find 'powershell.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.` even after changing the VS setting to NOT load windows powershell, but instead CMD only. The cmd window then doesn't allow anything to be typed or sent, and pressing ctrl c just inputs `^C`

I only noticed these points of failure after a few days of messing with creating a node.js application, so I'm assuming it was something I did during that time. I've listed as many possible changes or installations that I think could be a contributing cause:

1. Installed MongoDB, Robo 3T, GitHub Desktop, WinSCP, OpenSSH, Visual Studio Code
2. Accessed an Amazon EC2 instance through WinSCP, Cmder (default and laragon)
3. Installed npm packages on the instance with these programs, although took a few attempts.
4. Created a new nodejs project and installed npm packages.

All of these steps might have failed multiple times, and required older versions to be installed, and then again another version to change to ensure compatibility with something else because that also required an older version.

Notably, I had to remove openSSH from my path variable because it was completely breaking Visual Studio projects from even loading (I guess it would cause .NET core to fail to open).

my current path variable: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Applications\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

I'm not even sure where to begin fixing this issue other than nuking my PC with a fresh windows install, but I REALLY don't want to do that if it's unnecessary.

EDIT: Updating my user environment variables with both `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\system32` fixed my issues numbered 1 and 3.

Comment: Well.. I see one red flag right out of the gate.  You are missing the X:\Windows and X:\Windows\system32 directories in your path.  Every single application you run will need these directories to find system DLLs (and the like).  BTW, if it wasn't obvious, X:\ is *probably* C:\ on your system.  One other thing.. almost every utility you refer to is native to Linux.  You might try using WSL (or VirtualBox, etc) for a better experience.  In your case, I would suggest WSL1 and not 2.. it's more simple in its integration.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Interestingly I've barely had any DLL errors on this PC, I think maybe once a very long time ago. I will also look at the linux based suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Yeah.. findstr.exe is in your `windows\system32` directory.  Powershell is in `x:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`.  Start there for the two specific things you mentioned above.  Good luck! :)

Comment: I can confirm that adding the `X:\Windows` and `X:\Windows\system32` directories in my path fixed the findstr.exe issue so my context menu cmder and cmder.exe both now work with no sign of issues. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome :)